# Azure AD Application Certificates

Tags: azure, active-directory, x509

I'm trying to find a way to upload my own SAML X509 certificate for use with Azure AD application authentication.  Is this possible?

I ask because I'm trying to use the same Authentication Federation XML/X509 from Kronos for Kronos Mobile.  Since they're 2 different applications, it's generating its own certificate for each application and need to use the one x509 certificate for both applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to certificate for user or certificate which is uploaded when you are configuring your application as custom SAML application in Azure AD?

If latter - there is option for this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-custom-apps

On the forth screen from the top there is checkbox you need to check - "Configure the certificate ... "